# How to achieve expected RPS using Two Concurrency Thread Groups (or more), each with its own samplers and Throughput Shaping Timers?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

In JMeter 5.4.1, I am using 2 Concurrency Thread Groups in a test plan and each has a configuration as such:

```
${__tstFeedback(ThroughputShapingTimerXML,1,1000,10)}
```

Each thread group has 1 HTTP sampler underneath it and each HTTP sampler has a Throughout Shaping Timer

Here is my test plan:
[image]

Here is an example Throughput Shaping Timer configuration:
[image]

My intention is to be able to achieve 1 RPS on each sampler for the first X seconds, but apparently, it is splitting the 1RPS between the two samplers and trying to achieve in total 1 RPS, even though each concurrency thread group has it's own separate Throughout Shaping Timer.

There is the result I am getting:
[image]

My expectation was that the samplers would generate ~1 RPS load each and the total would be ~2.

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

[Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) chart displays 2 RPS for the 2 Throughput Shaping Timers configured for sending 1 RPS

Server Hits Per Second graph can be installed as a part of **5 Additional Graphs** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) or there is the same chart in the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: I tried the Server Hits Per Second plugin and it did show 2 hits per second for the first 1.5 minutes of leaving it running. Then it started oscillating between 2 and 1. But in this time the Aggregate Report listener, showed from the start the tendency towards 1.1 on Total  row in the Throughput column. Can you try leaving it running for 5 minutes to see if you get the same behavior as I did?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar setup as the topic starter and here is what I have in 'Hits per second' listener (As Dmitri, I had 1 RPS max in Throughput Shaping Timer)

[image]

In some cases, I had no more than 1 hit per second. My guess here is that one API is twice slower than the other, which produced inconsistent results. I might be wrong though..

Comment: I could not find an answer for this problem. To me it looks like something in JMeter is having an issue in properly managing the threads execution for maintaining the specified RPS (The api can for sure take that load ). It's either that OR I am not using the chosen test elements as they are supposed to be used... I compared what the 'Hits per second' listener is showing with what the Aggregate Report listener is showing on the Throughput column. I would raise a new question if I were you. Maybe we find out something more. :)